# Sort an NSSet of UITouches by y component of touch point

Tags: coordinates, uitouch, nsset

I have an NSSet of UITouches.

I can get the coordinates of a touch as follows:

```
CGPoint touchPosition = [myTouch locationInView:myTouch.window];
```

My set contains 4 touches, and I need to sort them by the y component of their touchPosition.
What would be the best approach for doing this?

thanks

Comment: Go to the documentation of `NSSet` and find "sort".

Comment: Well, duh, thank you. Obviously I did. I'm looking at NSArray *sortedArray = [mySetOfTouches sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors] but I haven't got a clue how to formulate the Descriptor in this case.

Comment: `+[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:comparator:]`, the key is `self`. Or `-[NSSet allObjects]` and `-[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:]`.

Comment: Thanks. That works for me. I hoped there would be a less wordy approach.